# Remove html entities in forum topic

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using drupal advanced forum, due to migration from phpbb to D7 forum I noticed there are some HTML entities shown in my forum topic. I need to handle this in the tpl file. Can you please let me know where to implement it.

[image: Screen shot special characters]

Comment: Maybe it's not a template thing. When you edit the forum node/topic (ex: `/node/4/edit`) does the node title have `&amp;` in it?

Comment: Yes, It has the &amp; in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like data transformation problem; the import didn't format the HTML entity title data on import. Instead of trying to code around the problem in your template, you should reformat your node titles.

Run a code snippet (e.g. `drush scr myscript.php`) that can fix the formatting on your nodes. Something like:

```
// @TODO: Retrieve your list of imported node nids in the $nids array
$nids = array(4, 5); 
foreach ($nids as $nid) {
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node->title = html_entity_decode($node->title);
  node_save($node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Will try the code.                                                                            Also, can you let me know if i need to try formatting in the tpl file where should i do. I found advanced-forum-topic-list-view.tpl.php is used for display. But i am not sure where to format the title. Please suggest.

Comment: I've not used that module so I don't know. I'll reiterate this is a data transformation problem and not a display problem. Hacking the template to do the transformation for you is a bad idea. If you're set on doing this in the theme layer, you should do it in a `template_preprocess_node()` invocation.